# How to apply a code for multiple columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I am new to R and have the following example code that I wish to apply for every column in my data.

```
data(economics, package="ggplot2")
economics$index <- 1:nrow(economics)
loessMod10 <- loess(uempmed ~ index, data=economics, span=0.10)
smoothed10 <- predict(loessMod10)
plot(economics$uempmed, x=economics$date, type="l", main="Loess Smoothing and Prediction", xlab="Date", ylab="Unemployment (Median)")
lines(smoothed10, x=economics$date, col="red")
```

Could someone please suggest how this would be possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to perform loess smoothing within ggplot.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
df <- economics
##
#
gg.melt <- setDT(df) |> melt(id='date', variable.name = 'KPI')
ggplot(gg.melt, aes(x=date, y=value))+
  geom_line()+
  stat_smooth(method=loess, color='red', size=0.5, se=FALSE, method.args = list(span=0.1))+
  facet_wrap(~KPI, scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

Regarding combining everything on one plot I'm not seeing how you would do that as the y-scales are so different. If the point is to see how the peaks line up, etc. you could do this:

```
ggplot(gg.melt, aes(x=date, y=value))+
  geom_line()+
  stat_smooth(method=loess, color='red', size=0.5, se=FALSE, method.args = list(span=0.1))+
  facet_grid(KPI~., scales = 'free_y')
```

[image]

There is also the `dygraphs` package which allows creation of dynamic graphics that can be saved to html:

```
gg.melt[, scaled:=scale(value, center = FALSE, scale=diff(range(value))), by=.(KPI)]
gg.melt[, pred:=predict(loess(scaled~as.integer(date), .SD, span=0.1)), by=.(KPI)]
gg.dt <- dcast(gg.melt, date~KPI, value.var = list('scaled', 'pred'))
library(dygraphs)
dygraph(gg.dt) |>
  dyCrosshair(direction = 'vertical') |>
  dyRangeSelector()
```

[image]

It's possible to create a `dygraph(...)` version of the second plot, where the different KPI are in different facets, but you have to use RMarkdown for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your data from wide to long by the date and use `facet_wrap`. Maybe you want something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

economics %>%
  melt(., "date") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

Output:

[image]

#### Comment: All plots in one graph

If you mean all plots in one graph, you can give the variables a color like this:

```
economics %>%
  melt(., "date") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(date, value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_y_log10()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it also possible to have all plots on one graph after smoothing?

Comment: Hi @GemmaHowie, I added some code to create all the plots in one graph.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately this wont work for me as I have to save loess as output and then plot all the outputs of loess.